# Call parent's method for Local-Registration component VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have Vue object:

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#my-id',
    data() {
        return {
            example: 1
        }
    },
    methods: {
        exampleMethos(data) {
            console.log('data', data);
        }
    },
    components: {
        'my-component': {
            methods: {
                callMethod() {
                    console.log('I want call exampleMethos here');
                }
            },
            template: `
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" :change="callMethod()">
      </div>`
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="my-id">
  <my-component></my-component>
  <my-component></my-component>
  <my-component></my-component>
  <my-component></my-component>
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js "></script>
```

I know that i can use custom event in my-component:

with send event :

```
this.$emit('call', 'data');
```

but i just want call only exampleMethos and my-component is Local-Registration  inside 'app'.
Can I call exampleMethos  without use @call in html ?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are,But it's not the best practice, which can result in child components and parent component coupling.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    child: {
      template: `<div><button @click="btnClick">call parent method</button></div>`,
      methods: {
        btnClick () {
          this.$parent.fn()
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fn(){
      alert('parent method called')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child></child>
</div>
```